# Moodle plugin development testing

Tags: plugins, moodle

Hello Im new to moodle plugin development and I want to some changes on the current plugin. My problem now is how can I test the moodle plugin I am developing.

Answer (score 0):

Install a local copy of Moodle ( https://docs.moodle.org/en/Installing_Moodle ) or use a Docker image ( https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker ).

Add your plugin code to the relevant subdirectory with the locally installed copy of Moodle.

Configure the site with some suitable test data (or take a copy of your production database and remove user email addresses). Log into the site with suitable user accounts and test your plugin.

Ideally, you should also write (and run) both Unit tests ( https://docs.moodle.org/dev/PHPUnit ) and acceptance tests ( https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Running_acceptance_test ).